# Compare two sorted vector of numbers (Performance being priority)

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to explore as are there any better ways of comparing two vectors of the same size.

Intention: I have a `vector` of `vectors` named `table`. Each `vector` is of the same size. They consist of numbers ranging from `0-1000`.

What would be recommended the way of sorting the data structure named `table` in this case? Here, sorting refers to the `table` being sorted. Each element of the `table` is already sorted. The criterion for comparing `vector v1` and `vector v2` (lexicographical comparison). `v1` is smaller than `v2` if and only if the value at the first index `l` where `v1[l] != v2[l]`, it holds the property `v1[l] < v2[l]`.

Currently, I am using the following code snippet. I believe there would be a more efficient way from the fact the `vectors` are all sorted. Also, the size of each `vector` in the `table` is roughly around `4-10`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> table;
/* code that populates vector named table */
std::sort(table.begin(), table.end(), [](const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs) { return lhs < rhs; });
```

Comment: I did not quite get what you want to sort. Each vector inside the outer vector or the outer vector itself?

Comment: What would be your criterion for deciding "this inner vector of `table` should be placed before that one?"

Comment: @Peter I have added the criterion in the post

Comment: Since you essentially want lexicographical comparison - which stops on finding the first pair that are not equal, and the result is based on comparison of elements of the last pair - your question has no solution.

Comment: "Also, the size of each vector in the table is roughly around 4-10" this is a **hudge** problem. The size of the vectors is enormous. At this size the comparison will take forever. Like ... forever... Like beyond forever... You need to optimize this to the bone. I strongly suggest **hand coded assembler**. And since "performance is priority don't even bother to **profile** the program. Profiling is for when you don't care about performance.

Comment: STL already do many optimisations... so usually, you just have to ensure you take the appropriate container depending of what you want to do. Do you have any performance problem with the above code or you are trying to do premature optimisation? Except if you millions of items to sort, you should not have to worry too much about performance for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

`operator<` of `vector` performs [lexicographical comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare), i.e. it looks at the first position that is different in the two `vectors` and performs a comparison of the values at this position. This is about as optimal as it gets and having your `vectors` sorted won't make it any more efficient. You *could* write your own comparison function that (in contrast to `operator<`) assumes that the `vectors` are of equal size, but I doubt that would be worth the effort.

**Edit**: Some explanation why this is optimal (in some sense): Given that the order of the vectors should be based on their contents, you have to inspect at least one position. You compare the values at this postition, and if they are unequal, you're done. If not, you have no choice but to inspect another position, and so forth. The only thing that could be optimized here is the order in which the positions are inspected, trying to inspect postions that vary more strongly first. If that is possible depends, of course, on your use case. If you sort vectors much more often than you change them, you could also calculate some kind of hash for every vector and compare these.

**Another Edit**: There is in fact one small thing you can do: If you go through the vectors in sorted order and encounter the largest possible value your vector can contain, you don't have to inspect any further postions, because these will be equal anyway. The first vector therefore cannot be smaller. This is the only situation where the fact that the vectors are sorted makes it possible to predict the value of all the postitions that have not yet been inspected, so there should not be any further possible optimizations.